# ошибки > Configure project :launcher, Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed unity

Tags: unity3d-android, build

Не могу сбилдить проект из за этих ошибок, только что переустанавливал unity, тыкал разные настройки, в инете ищу уже 2 часа не могу понять в чем проблема. Я создал новый чистый проект в unity и ошибка такая же, перед обновлением unity была такая же ошибка на версии 2021.3.14f1. Я понятия не имею как и почему это произошло, хотя раньше все прекрасно работало (2 месяца, я не открывал unity до этого момента). На старых проектах которые до этого собирались отлично и без ошибок, все тоже самое.

Первое предупреждение "Unable to find player assembly: /Users/karabok/Documents/Unity Progect/My project (1) test/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll"

```
     #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [BurstAotCompiler.cs:209] Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:527] UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
 #6  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 #7 mono_jit_runtime_invoke
 #8 do_runtime_invoke
 #9 mono_runtime_invoke
 #10 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #11 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #12 Scripting::UnityEditor::Build::BuildPipelineInterfacesProxy::OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs(ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingExceptionPtr*)
 #13 BuildPlayerScriptDLLs(BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, ScriptingObjectPtr, BuildPlayerOptions, bool, ScriptingAssemblies&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
 #14 BuildPlayerData(BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, int, BuildPlayerOptions, BuildCompression const&, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul> const&, AssetBundleBuildData*, std::__1::vector<EditorSceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)124, 16> >&, ScriptingObjectPtr, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&, std::__1::set<PPtr<Prefab>, std::__1::less<PPtr<Prefab> >, std::__1::allocator<PPtr<Prefab> > >&, BuildPlayerSetup const&)
 #15 DoBuildPlayer_Build(BuildPlayerSetup const&, std::__1::vector<EditorSceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)124, 16> >&, BuildPlayerOptions, BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul> const&, bool, ScriptingObjectPtr&, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
 #16 DoBuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, std::__1::vector<EditorSceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)124, 16> >&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul> const&, bool, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
 #17 BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, BuildReporting::BuildReport&)
 #18 BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, int, BuildPlayerOptions, ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, unsigned char)
 #19  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
 #20  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:170] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
 #21  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
 #22  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1172] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
```

Первая ошибка "> Configure project :launcher"

```
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
47 actionable tasks: 47 executed
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
 #6  (Mono JIT Code) [PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:371] UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
 #7  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 #8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke
 #9 do_runtime_invoke
 #10 mono_runtime_invoke
 #11 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #12 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #13 CallMono(char const*, char const*, char const*, ScriptingArguments const&)
 #14 DoBuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, std::__1::vector<EditorSceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)124, 16> >&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul> const&, bool, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
 #15 BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, BuildReporting::BuildReport&)
 #16 BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, int, BuildPlayerOptions, ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, unsigned char)
 #17  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
 #18  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:170] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
 #19  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
 #20  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1172] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
```

Вторая ошибка "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

```
    Note: /Users/karabok/Documents/Unity Progect/My project (1) test/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/Users/karabok/.android/debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
 #6  (Mono JIT Code) [PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:371] UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
 #7  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 #8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke
 #9 do_runtime_invoke
 #10 mono_runtime_invoke
 #11 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #12 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #13 CallMono(char const*, char const*, char const*, ScriptingArguments const&)
 #14 DoBuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, std::__1::vector<EditorSceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)124, 16> >&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul> const&, bool, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
 #15 BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, BuildReporting::BuildReport&)
 #16 BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, BuildTargetPlatformGroup, BuildTargetPlatform, int, BuildPlayerOptions, ScriptingBackendNativeArrayPtrOpaque*, unsigned char)
 #17  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
 #18  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:170] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
 #19  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
 #20  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1172] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
```

Третья ошибка "CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed."

```
    /Users/karabok/Documents/Unity main/2021.3.23f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Users/karabok/Documents/Unity main/2021.3.23f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
MallocNanoZone = 0
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
SHELL = /bin/bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.XQyYUs1EPu/Listeners
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
HOME = /Users/karabok
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = com.unity3d.unityhub.7560
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0x7:0x31
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
TMPDIR = /var/folders/ts/84lxj0f93m3fywc39kl1zfsh0000gn/T/
LOGNAME = karabok
JAVA_HOME = /Users/karabok/Documents/Unity main/2021.3.23f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = /Users/karabok/Documents/Unity main/2021.3.23f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
USER = karabok
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Note: /Users/karabok/Documents/Unity Progect/My project (1) test/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/Mono2x/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/Users/karabok/.android/debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
47 actionable tasks: 47 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <ce2320f87b7248779ffc954a5e99fdef>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:370)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Четвертая ошибка "Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 216 seconds (216309 ms)"

```
    #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1172] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
```

Пятая ошибка "UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors"

```
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1172] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
```

[image: Ошибки в консоли unity]

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70917420/unity-error-on-m1-mac-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore-invalid-keystore-for
2. https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-gradle-build-error-in-unity-2d.1343267/
3. https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+KeytoolException+Failed+to+read+key+AndroidDebugKey+from+store+Invalid+keystore+format

Comment: TL;DR: попробуйте просто удалить `/Users/karabok/.android/debug.keystore` может поможет. Если нет, то надо восстановить, кто-то/что-то вам кейстор андроида "того"..

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Да, я сейчас этим и занимаюсь, у меня получилось сбилдить пустой проект, сейчас попробую на другом

Comment: @PeterSmith, все заработало! Спасибо вам больше, если можете, то напишите полноценный ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его, как "решенный"

Comment: Пожалуйста! Добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитесь находить корень ошибки, как правило нет нужды писать весь список, т.к. одна ошибка тянет за собой другую, и её решение чинит всё остальное. При этом можно смело игнорировать всякие warning, ищите именно то, что сломало вам билд. В данном случае ключевой момент я нашел в виде:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/Users/karabok/.android/debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

после этого воспользовался гуглом с запросом `unity KeytoolException Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store Invalid keystore format` к ключевым словам ошибки добавил ещё среду (unity), чтобы получить более релевантные ответы, т.к. в целом это ошибка тулчейна Java/Android SDK. Оттуда и получил рекомендации изложенные в комментарии.